# What is wrong with this circle's area problem?

Tags: circles

My solution and my book's solution don't match.

**Is something wrong with the my solution?

If so, where and why?**

My book says:

> The radius *r* of a circle increases by 50%.
>   In terms of *r*, what is the area of the circle 
>   with the increased radius?

My solution:

1. A = $\pi r^2\ $ *=> Area of any circle*
2. ir = $\ 3r/2 \ $ *=> Increased radio*
3. A$\ _{ir}  = \pi ir^{2}  \ $ *=> Area of circle with increased radio*
4. A$\ _{ir}  = \pi (3r/2 )^{2}  \ $ *=> Substituting **ir** with its value*
5. A$\ _{ir}  = \pi (9r^2/4 )  \ $ *=> Square*
6. A$\ _{ir}  = \ (9\pi r^2 )/4   \ $ *=> Result*

Is the *In terms of **r*** tricky?

Comment: What's the solution from your book?

Comment: @draks:  thanks for the interest, the book says:  $\  (4\pi r^2 )/3   \ $

Comment: @EmmadKareem: thanks. Not sure what does "Increased ratio" means, that is what the problem says. I am assuming that means 3r/2.

Comment: your book is wrong...

Comment: Well.....it took me a while, and I was getting crazy. The truth is that: I was looking at the wrong solution, the book is right...so embarrassed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your answer!